# How do I trigger audio to play on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a JavaScript function where when the user scrolls down the page at a certain point (800 px) my audio file plays. I do not know how to properly write the JavaScript but I believe it needs to incorporate an if statement. Can someone please help.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const play = document.querySelector('.play');

  if (window.scrollY > 800) {
  document.getElementById("playAudio").play();
    }
  });
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section{
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.one{
    background:brown ;
}

.two{
    background: pink;
}

.three{
    background:lightgreen ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Audio on scroll</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <section class="one"></section>

  <section class="two">
  <div class="play">
    <div id="playAudio">
    <audio autoplay     src="audio/myaudio.mp3"></audio>
     </div>
    </div>
    </section>

  <section class="three"></section>
  
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @krampus I would like it to play only once.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure the if statement is inside the event listener function. You need to call the `play()` method on your audio element. Like:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const playAudio = document.querySelector("#playAudio audio");
  if (window.scrollY > 800) {
    playAudio.play();
  }
});
```

This will start playing the audio when you’ve scrolled more than 800px down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should put an if statement inside your listener function and check the current scroll amount.
Also, you should select the audio element and not its container.

In your example the maximum scroll possible is less than `800px` so I changed it to `200px` for the example.

```js
let isPLaying = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

  const audio = document.querySelector("#playAudio audio");
  if (!isPLaying && window.scrollY > 200) {
    console.log("play")
    audio.play();
    isPLaying = true
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one {
  background: brown;
}

.two {
  background: pink;
}

.three {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Audio on scroll</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <section class="one"></section>

  <section class="two">
    <div class="play">
      <div id="playAudio">
        <audio autoplay src="audio/myaudio.mp3"></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="three"></section>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Notice how I added a boolean to the event listener so the music will only play one time.

Comment: thank you for your help but the audio did not play.

Comment: Do you actually have an audio file under the `audio/myaudio.mp3` path? Also I changed my answer to the scroll event will trigger the `play` function only once

Comment: Yes I do have an audio file under that path. I did some research and the audio might not be playing because most browsers do not allow audio to play without the user interacting with an element like button.